# blocking access to all post/tag URIs via htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to block all access to the `post/tag/example-here` pages on a WordPress site, but the following does not work.  The `.htaccess` access file is being parsed.  It is at the root of the site (ie the `public_html`) on a regular cPanel account.  I've tried with and without the leading slash.  I don't understand why it wouldn't be working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^post/tag/
RewriteRule .* - [F]
   
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^post/tag/
> RewriteRule .* - [F]
> ```

The `REQUEST_URI` server var does start with a slash (it is a full root-relative URL-path), although you do say you have tried this "with and without the leading slash", so this should have worked if that is what you are referring to and `/post` is the first path-segment in the URL-path.

However, you don't need the additional `RewriteCond` directive here as the URL check can (and should) be performed in the `RewriteRule` directive instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^post/tag/ - [F]
```

In this case, there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

---

If that is still failing then try matching against `THE_REQUEST` instead, which contains the first line of the request headers and is not modified by other rewrites (unlike `REQUEST_URI` and the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/post/tag/
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`THE_REQUEST` would contain a string of the form:

```
GET /post/tag/example-here HTTP/1.1
```

---

Still not working... then make sure you don't have a custom 403 `ErrorDocument` that is routing the request through WordPress. If you have not defined anything yourself, then this could still be defined in the server config (by your host), which you can reset to the Apache default with the following in `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

Comment: Much thanx - the 403 was routed back to the site. Adding "ErrorDocument 403 default" fixed it!